# When introducing new data against the model an error is produced, this is due to some new words within sentences, how to adapt R code for it to work?

Tags: machine-learning, r

In the R code below, I included the sentences when looking to compare the manually classified with lexicon dictionary results by positive, negative and neutral (in matrixdata1), the algorithms results for the model produces different outcome in the tables, which is good. However, when executing..

```
results2 = classify_models(container2, models)
```

..when feeding in new data `(matrixdata2)` against the model it produces an error message:

```
Error in predict.svm(model, container@classification_matrix, prob = TRUE,  : 
  test data does not match model !
```

In checking the datasets, I understand the train set's sentences used to create the model contains specific words, but the new data fed against the model include new words not recognised in the train set. I am wondering how to overcome this problem. Few options I am thinking of are  the following:-

- Limit sentences in the new data to include only words that are in the train set,
- Or point the ML to consult the dictionaries to look up additional words
- Or for the machine learning process to identify ones that match and ones that do not match simply say I don't know response from ML.

What is the best option to overcome the problem? What would I need to translate this idea into adapting the R code below?

**Update: 18/04**

I created a few sentences that contained only words that appeared in the creation of the model. I fed in this few sentences with its labelled sentiment (new data) in against the model, but it still produced the same error message above. I do not understand why this is the case as these words are recognised in the trainset. However, when I used one of the same sentences in the new data to feed in against the model, it worked, so from what I can tell is if the sentence does not exactly match whats in the trainset, then it produces the error. I am unsure how to overcome this, please help me resolve this problem.

```
#Load Libraries
library(RTextTools) #RTextTools available for 3.4.1
library(e1071)
library(gmodels)

setwd(directory/path)
text= read.csv("matrixdata1.csv", header = FALSE)

# build dtm
matrix= create_matrix(text[,1:2])
mat = as.matrix(matrix)

# build the data to specify response variable, training set, testing set.
container = create_container(mat, as.numeric(as.factor(text[,3])),
                             trainSize=1:672, testSize=673:840,virgin=FALSE)

models = train_models(container, algorithms=c("MAXENT" , "SVM", "RF", "BAGGING", "TREE"), set_heldout = 168) 

#container1
results1 = classify_models(container, models)

text2 = read.csv("matrixdata2.csv", header = FALSE) 
matrix2= create_matrix(text2[,1:2])
mat2 = as.matrix(matrix2)

container2 = create_container(mat2, labels=NULL, trainSize=1:500,testSize=NULL, virgin=TRUE)

#Results from feeding in new data against the model
#When running this code below, it produces the error message outlined above in the description of the problem.
results2 = classify_models(container2, models)
```

[Datasets used in the R code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GhzOY4IupXXFxKUPaiBsNgpZwxY84Xha?usp=sharing)